# Is there any way to convert a closed path into a polygon in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

Basically, I am working on a strategy game, and provinces on the map are basically comprised of a list of border points (which are used to create a Polygon).

I thought that loading the points from a SVG file "polygon" tag would be a great idea. However, Inkscape doesn't appear to have any way to convert my closed paths into polygons, and loading from a "path" would be relatively difficult because I would have to write code to "follow" the path during curves and add points at regular intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very close to what you ask but not quite. As they will be paths in both cases although just simple straight segment paths:

1. Select the path in question.
2. Choose **Extensions → Modify Path → Add Nodes...**

   - Set mode to *By max. Segment Legth*
   - Set legth of segment
3. Choose **Extensions → Modify Path → Straighten Segments...**

[image]

**Image 1**: Original path (top), result after polygonisation (bottom)

Or alternatively you can probably also use **Extensions → Modify Path → Flatten Beziers...**, for a more usable polygon. But your mileage may vary.

[image]

**Image 1**: after applying flatten beziers

On the other hand you can do this in a browser easily. Although a fully linear path is almost just as easy to parse as a polygon (it has 2 or 3 letters in the thing otherwise its just a list of points)

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I think I might run the resulting file through an obline path->polygon tool for simplicity (I did some digging and found one).