# Converting lines into closed polygons in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I've traced an image (in this case, grand canyon) and it composed of several individual line segments. But now I want to give each of the closed shapes (again, not closed shapes, it just seem like it) a different fill color.

Is there any way I can close the shapes and convert them into polygons?

Earlier post did not answer my question ([Is there any way to convert a closed path into a polygon in Inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107810/is-there-any-way-to-convert-a-closed-path-into-a-polygon-in-inkscape))
[image]

Comment: @BillyKerr that's it! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a work-around that requires a good bit of manual operation, although someone more experienced than I may take the foundation and provide the accessory operation.

Convert your lines to paths using Path, Stroke to path. What was one a single set of nodes is now a series of double path nodes.

[image: starting image]

The above is a sample/test scribble with one true closed path (lower left) and one tacked on path.

[image: single set of nodes]

In the image above, one can see a single set of nodes that delineate the path and that the tacked-on segment is not selected, but would look the same.

[image: double path nodes]

This image shows that each stroke is now a polygon and specifically a closed path.

[image: no fill small stroke]

This image has had the fill removed and the stroke changed to a miniscule amount. It would be invisible at lower zoom levels. The nodes are visible, as is the overlap.

It is necessary to trim, break or otherwise prune those paths which would not become part of the desired fill. For the complete path, exercise caution where it joins the imcomplete path. If you have fill turned on varying colors you'll be able to see quickly the changes if a break or trim or join goes awry.

[image: filled inner]

This image shows the original complete path with a colored fill as well as the nodes now independently assigned to the inner path.

[image: second color filled]

This is the result of the joining of the second tacked-on point to the outer path of the completed stroke converted to path. The unfilled path is a perimeter to the overall shape.

Obviously, there's a thin line between the colors.

[image: path dynamic offset]

I selected the green path, then Path, Dynamic offset and dragged it until the gap disappeared. Some massaging was necessary in the tiny peninsula on the yellow lower left, by pushing a node about.

I'm not experienced enough to know a faster-than-manual method to address the dual path intersection between the tacked-on pseudo-complete paths.